# Number of files in directory

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am on Windows 10. I currently doing a group assignment that deals with a lot of images. I want to know when I click on an image if there is a way for the file explorer to tell me that this is "X" (for example 10th) item in this directory. I only see the total number of items on the bottom left corner of the file explorer screen. I know it sounds very nooby haha.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: This is meaningless unless the directory listing is first sorted. File systems in general don't sort the order of entries in a directory, and adding and removing files can change the order. NTFS happens to use a simplistic lexical sorting when storing entries in the directory b-tree data structure. That doesn't apply to other file systems such as FAT32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **PowerShell** is an option:

```
ls | % {$i=1} { "$i $_"; $i++}
```

This will return:

```
1 file1.jpg
2 file2.jpg
3 file3.jpg
...
```